# Integrating library using cocoapods with workspace

Tags: ios, cocoapods, mmdrawercontroller

I am using [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) library using cocoapods. I get following exception, can someone please help me to resolve it?

```
-[MenuViewController mm_visibleDrawerFrame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb01f150
```

I have uploaded sample project to show the way I am using this pod - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72253873/PodTest.zip. Open PodTest workspace and If you run PodExampleProject you will get above exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. I needed to add `-all_load` in my project.